# How to automatically commit and push changes to a git repository preferably in eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, autocommit

Is there a way to automatically commit and push everything in the local repository to remote one at a scheduled time of the day??

If yes can it be done with eclipse git plugin??

regards,
Atish

Comment: Check out [crontab](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html). `0 8 * * * cd /path/to/repo && git commit -am "Daily commit" && git push origin` may help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a plugin with startup extension( org.eclipse.ui.startup ), having one thread waiting for the specific time of the day and for the git part there is a library [jGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), which you can use to create a plugin in Eclipse.

Use org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RepositoryBuilder class to find your repository with Java, and the [API](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/package-summary.html) package for the git commands.

But bare in mind that if you implement it as an Eclipse plugin you will need to have Eclipse opened at that time of the day.